Why didn't the force field protect me from this explosion in Bomber Friends?
I used the force field in a game of Bomber Friends (Battle Arena mode), but it didn't protect me from this explosion (see the player in the top left corner with the white hairs):

Why?

Force field:


The force field takes a bit of time (ca. between 1 and 2 seconds) to activate.

Yellow force field = not activated yet
Blue force field = activated yet

E.g., see:

The player with the yellow force field died since the force field was not activated yet, whereas the player with the blue force field survived since the force field was activated.
